# My Lambda is throwing a invoke error timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, timeout, invoke

Normally my lambda runs fine, today I am starting to receive this error:

```
ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
    "errorType": "TimeoutError",
    "errorMessage": "Connection timed out after 120000ms",
    "code": "TimeoutError",
    "message": "Connection timed out after 120000ms",
    "time": "2020-11-27T10:34:39.272Z",
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "hostname": "lambda.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
    "retryable": true,
    "stack": [
        "TimeoutError: Connection timed out after 120000ms",
        "    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:83:34)",
        "    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)",
        "    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)",
        "    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)",
        "    at TLSSocket.emitRequestTimeout (_http_client.js:673:40)",
        "    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)",
        "    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)",
        "    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)",
        "    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:443:8)",
        "    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)"
    ]
}
```

I don't have any clue what might be causing this, I know that this lambda invokes several lambdas and awaits on all of them to conclude, I checked the logs on cloudwatch for each one and all of them had completed with success.

Here is a snippet of the code I use to trigger all those child lambdas and wait for them:

```
function invokeAll(){

const baseLambdaPayload = {
  arg1: args.myarg1,
  arg2: args.myarg2,
  arg3: args.myarg3,
  arg4: args.myarg4
};

lambdaInvocations = [
  ...lambdaInvocations,
  triggerLamdba(
    'lambda1', {
      ...baseLambdaPayload,
      morePayload: await getMorePayload()
    }),
  triggerLamdba(
    'lambda2', baseLambdaPayload),
  triggerLamdba(
    'lambda3', baseLambdaPayload),
  triggerLamdba(
    'lambda4', baseLambdaPayload)
];

return await Promise.all(lambdaInvocations);
}

const triggerLamdba = (name, payload) => {
  const params = {
    FunctionName: name,
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    Payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  return lambda.invoke(params).promise();
}
```

Any tips to where I should look into? Thanks.

Comment: Is your function associated with a VPC?

Comment: One of those child lambdas, yes it is, just noticed now.

Comment: Lambda in VPC does not have internet access, unless you place it in a private subnet behind a nat gateway.

Comment: So a lambda in vpc calls other functions? If yes, you can also use VPC interface endpoint.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the timeouts on the Lambda functions? Do you know which child function is causing the problem? (Perhaps include/exclude them to identify the culprit.)